# Java equivalent of C# generic array declaration?

Tags: java, c#, generics

I have a generic class I'd like to convert from C# to Java.  The class starts off this way:

```
   public class StackImplementationUsingDynamicArray<T>
    {
        private T[] _array = new T[10];
    }
```

I can't seem to get the equivalent Java code for the declaration.  This code at least compiles (with a warning) but throws a runtime exception:

```
   public class StackImplementationUsingDynamicArray<T>
    {
        private T[] _array = (T[])Array.newInstance (StackImplementationUsingDynamicArray.class, 10);
    }
```

Is it possible to do this in Java?  What should the code be?  Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Comment: `Deque<T> likeThis = new ArrayDeque<>();`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Why `new ArrayDeque<>()` and not `new ArrayList<>(10)`? Since it's to be used as a replacement for an array, wouldn't you need the `get(int)` method of `List`?

Comment: @Andreas Sorry, I would replace `StackImplementationUsingDynamicArray` with an `ArrayDeque`. Since that's what it (basically) is. From the [`Deque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) Javadoc, *Deques can also be used as LIFO (Last-In-First-Out) stacks. This interface should be used in preference to the legacy Stack class. When a deque is used as a stack, elements are pushed and popped from the beginning of the deque.*

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts.  This is actually just 'practice' as I work on learning Java.  I had some earlier C# code I had written as practice for interviews - and this was one of the routines.  I had several implementations of a stack - a dynamic array being just one.  ArrayList would have made it too easy :)  And I did see the answers to similar questions but - I was missing something.  Erwin's answer made it crystal clear and I was able to finish.  Turns out that Java is just different enough from C# to keep me on my toes...

Answer (score 1):

Yes - but you need to pass the class object of the actual type to the constructor of the class:

```
public class StackImplementationUsingDynamicArray<T>
{
    private T[] _array;
    public StackImplementationUsingDynamicArray(Class<T> clazz) {
        _array = (T[]) Array.newInstance(clazz, 10);
    }
```

Which you can then use like this:

```
StackImplementationUsingDynamicArray<String> a =
        new StackImplementationUsingDynamicArray<>(String.class);
```

Comment: Thanks Erwin.  This is exactly the explanation I needed.